# Python shortcode to html

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, shortcode

Hi I get a string response from an api in the form of shortcode. I want to parse it to html to be pushed to a website that only accepts html or markup

I am using python 2.7

I was thinking of writing a

```
 description = re.sub('\[vc_sub_header\]','<h1>'description)
 description = re.sub('\[\\vc_sub_header\]','<h1>'description)
```

but some of the shortcode elements contain a css class which i need to ignore.

Here is a snippet of the response I am having to parse:

```
[vc_column_text css=\".vc_custom_1536261801005{margin-bottom: 0px !important;border-bottom-width: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;}\"]On 5 September 2018 [/vc_column_text]
```

I want to parse elements ignoring the css text :

```
[vc_column_text css=\".vc_custom_1536261801005{margin-bottom: 0px !important;border-bottom-width: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 0px !important;}\"]
```

to `<p>`

I was thinking of using regex but it is difficult becasue I don't know how to ignore the css part.

Comment: Daniel, the answer to your question is "For God's sake don't try to do this with ad hoc regexps! You will just cause yourself a lot of headaches. Look for a library that can read this shortcode format and convert it to html, or to something else that you can further convert." But recommending a library is off-topic on this site, as the close message explains.

Comment: The issue was that I couldn't find a library that does the parsing so I am having to resort to regex manipulation and re.sub

Comment: How long did you spend looking? Did you google "python shortcode", and what's wrong with the [shortcodes](https://pypi.org/project/shortcodes/) module? If you tried using this module and ran into trouble, asking for (specific) help with your code _would_ be on topic on this site.

Comment: cannot use the shortcodes module since I am locked to python 2.7. I spent ages looking. Still no success :(

Comment: Aha, now it's starting to make sense. Well, but it's one file of about 250 lines. My recommendation: Figure out how to rewrite it to work on Python 2. It'll be far less trouble than cobbling together your own, and you might learn some cool things about Python.

Comment: I just looked at it, it'll be almost no work to get it to run on Python 2.7. Do it!

Comment: That shortcode library you might as well just re.sub since you still have to 'register' the elements you wish to parse out.

Comment: Daniel, the example shortcode you posted has an attribute with css embedded in braces. Even if you don't want to interpret it, you need to skip over it. I'd give the library a try, if only so I have someone _else_ to swear at if things go south...